# Blender Video Editor Preview doesn't show any image

Tags: video-sequence-editor

[image]I've been using Blender for over a year now, and this is the first time I have had this problem. I am editing a small 2000 frame video, but ever since I saved it the preview will not show images or play audio clips. Rendering it still upholds the transparent (checkered) image.
But, there is one thing. A singular picture shows around the 1500 mark and a singular video clip shows directly after. After this video clip the preview goes back to transparent. This shows that there is not a problem with preview, but with the settings.

What could have caused this? It's a genuine emergency that I have to resolve ASAP.

Comment: Please sahre your rendering settings

Comment: @MFarooqi what settings would you like to see?

Comment: render properties and output properties..

Comment: @MFarooqi I added the picture into the initial post.

Comment: would you mind to attach a timeline preview along with proxy and cache + media properties.. or if possible please share your blender file.

Comment: Also please share the preview window.. where you can't see anything

Comment: Try to use the Sequence Render Animation in the VSE view menu.